# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable with spearmanr_coefficient

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to print out the Spearmanr Coefficient for two variables.

```
drat = cars['drat']
carb = cars['carb']
spearmanr_coefficient, p_value = spearmanr(drat, carb)
print('spearman is %0.3f' % (spearmanr_coefficient))
```

both drat and carb variables are 'float64' types.

Here is the error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-f64604af9a3c> in <module>()
      1 drat = cars['drat']
      2 carb = cars['carb']
----> 3 spearmanr_coefficient, p_value = spearmanr(drat, carb)
      4 print('spearman is %0.3f' % (spearmanr_coefficient))

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Can I convert the variable to ints? Is there another solution here?

I have tried using `.astype(int)` and `.astype(np.float32)` with no luck.

Scipy version: 1.0.0

Numpy version: 1.14.0

First 10 rows from each variable (below).

Drat

```
0     3.90
1     3.90
2     3.85
3     3.08
4     3.15
5     2.76
6     3.21
7     3.69
8     3.92
9     3.92
10    3.92
```

carb

```
0     4
1     4
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     1
6     4
7     2
8     2
9     4
10    4
```

Comment: Have you also tried `.astype(np.float32)`?

Comment: Can you also include the `scipy` and `numpy` versions you are using?

Comment: havent tried that.

Comment: scipy version 1.0.0

Comment: numpy version 1.14.0

Comment: Have you perhaps redefined `spearmanr` as a float?

Comment: If you hadn't, then it'll probably be easier to answer if you made some dummy data too for this to be reproducible :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman didn't work, got the same error

Comment: how would I redefine it as a flot?

Comment: For example, if at some point you had executed `spearmanr, p_value = spearmanr(drat, carb)`, then `spearmanr` would get redefined as a float. The next time you run that statement you would get an error because the `spearmanr` on the right-hand side would no longer refer to `scipy.stats.spearmanr`.

Comment: An easy way to confirm this guess is to put `print(spearmanr)` before the line which is raising the error: `spearmanr, p_value = spearmanr(drat, carb)`. If the output prints a number, at least you'll know the source of the problem.

Comment: interesting, `print(spearmanr)` just after defining the variables produces -0.125`. `print(spearmanr)` after `spearmanr_coefficient, p_value = spearmanr(drat, carb)` produces an error

Answer (score 0):

I just try, but can't reproduce your error.
Could you send a sample of your data?
Thank you!

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cars=pd.DataFrame({'drat':[1.2,2,3,4,5],'carb':[5,6.5,7,8,7]})
drat = cars['drat']
carb = cars['carb']
print drat.dtype, carb.dtype
spearmanr_coefficient, p_value =stats.spearmanr(drat, carb)
print('spearman is %0.3f' % (spearmanr_coefficient))
```

output:

```
float64 float64
spearman is 0.821
```

update data:

```
cars=pd.DataFrame({'drat':[3.9,3.9,3.85,3.08,3.15,2.76,3.21,3.69,3.92,3.92,3.92],carb':[4,4,1,1,2,1,4,2,2,4,4]})
```

output:

```
float64 int64
spearman is 0.620
```

Comment: first 10 rows of both are now included!

Comment: Could you show us the pd.dataframe you use? `yourDataframe.head().to_pickle('path/file')`, then just shall the file. OR Could you try to just run the first 10 raws, `drat = cars['drat'][0:10];carb = cars['carb'][0:10]` ?